# Weird CSS Transition Issue

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transitions

I'm using `transition` property in CSS in the navigation on my website. The navigation consists of 3 images. When you `hover` the image with the mouse, a `transition` is applied that displays an overlay with some text. This all works beautifully in Chrome and Firefox. Safari, however, is a mess. Not only does the transition behaviour not work at all, but no matter what I do, the menu stays on a second line rather than remaining on the first line with the logo (you'll see from the jsfiddle example what I mean if you open the fiddle in both Chrome and Safari).

**CSS:**

```
header nav a img {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menuitem-content {
    top: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: rgba(86, 81, 65, .8);
    display: none;
    transition: all 1.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s;
    font-size: 14pt;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0px;
}

header nav a:hover > .menuitem-content {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/35qnu4d1/

You might have to expand the output window a bit to see the menu and logo on the same line (which for our purposes is fine as the min resolution should be `1024x768` — this isn't build for mobile devices). Any ideas why it's behaving so weird in Safari?

Comment: You'll need to also add `display: -webkit-inline-flex;` for Safari. But as far as I see you could simply use `display: block;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use http://caniuse.com/#search=flex, you need `-webkit-...` vendor prefixes for all `flex` properties.
2. [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) isn't `animatable` property. You can't apply `transition` to it. See this [list of animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).
3. You don't need to use `display: inline-flex` with `position: absolute` — `display: block` is enough.

Check out my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/3q1wcxj2/1/).

**CSS:**

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #565141;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

header nav a:hover > .menuitem-content {
    display: block;
}

#content-body {
    background-color: #efefef;
    width: 97%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #565141;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```